# Why are these text-shadow effects not working?

Tags: html, css

```
     <p style="color: hsl(230, 100%, 50%); 
        text-shadow: 0 2px 0 0px hsl(330, 100%, 25%), 
         0 3px 2px 0px hsla(330, 100%, 15%, 0.5), 
         0 3px 0 3px hsl(350, 100%, 50%), 
         0 5px 0 3px hsl(350, 100%, 25%), 
         0 6px 2px 3px hsla(350, 100%, 15%, 0.5),  
         0 6px 0 9px hsl(20, 100%, 50%), 
         0 8px 0 9px hsl(20, 100%, 25%), 
         0 9px 2px 9px hsla(20, 100%, 15%, 0.5),  
         0 9px 0 18px hsl(50, 100%, 50%) 
         0 11px 0 18px hsl(50, 100%, 25%), 
         0 12px 2px 18px hsla(50, 100%, 15%, 0.5),  
         0 12px 0 30px hsl(70, 100%, 50%), 
         0 14px 0 30px hsl(70, 100%, 25%), 
         0 15px 2px 30px hsla(70, 100%, 15%, 0.5), 
         0 15px 0 45px hsl(90, 100%, 50%), 
         0 17px 0 45px hsl(90, 100%, 25%), 
         0 17px 2px 45px hsla(90, 100%, 15%, 0.5);">Text Shadow</p>
```

This is my code which i copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh867756.aspx
It should give effect of color happiness on that page. I am using Firefox 30. I also tried to open it in opera it does not work there either.
I tried to change hsla to rgb (I know that was useless but i just tried any ways).
I also removed all the new lines but still no text-shadow appears just plain simple text.Any hint why is it happening?

Comment: Why are you setting the CSS inside the `style` attribute of the `p` element? Why not make a class and wrap a `div` around it?

Comment: You are setting one parameter too many in those text-shadows. Remove the leading 0. Also, why the hell you want to set 17 different shadows in the same text?

Comment: I said i was following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh867756.aspx
This is exactly as written there. I tried removing leading zero also. That did not work

Comment: Well this is a Microsoft documentation, about Internet Explorer, not W3C about what is standard. I'm sure it will work in Internet Explorer 10 as is described in the article, I can't say the same about everything else.

Comment: beside the extra value not valid you are missing a `,` . no way that works :)

Comment: Thanx. I fixed the error with , . but why are on that site five parameters for every text-shadow and they claim it works.

Comment: Internet Explorer supports an additional "spread" value in `text-shadow`. No other browser does. When you're following an MSDN tutorial, you'll probably get results to match the tutorial more reliably if you use a Microsoft browser.

Comment: That means there is no easy way (or any) to achieve that effect on other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS text-shadow takes four values:** 
*distance-x*, *distance-y*, *blur*, and the *colour*.

E.G:

```
p { 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, 
               3px 3px 5px blue; 
}
```

Only IE accepts the extra *spread* value.

In addition (as commented) you are missing a comma between here:

```
0 9px 0 18px hsl(50, 100%, 50%)  <<<<
0 11px 0 18px hsl(50, 100%, 25%),
```

Comment: I removed leading zero from all text-shadows it still does not work.

Comment: @JayeshKakatkar as i commented , you are missing a `,` in between 2 values

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this effect on other browsers.

Comment: I was able to get this working on FF and IE10. I have not tried any other browser. It does not look identical, but does show a lot of color happiness.

Comment: Interesting, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals) says that "this takes *up to* four values" so I thought that one or two values would be OK, as in other properties.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use either:
 http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/
http://css3generator.com/ 
to generate the `text-shadow` code you need.

Use [**this reference**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) to familiarize yourself with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working in FF (v31), but like Moob stated: IE only takes the spread, so this fix is not an exact replica.  I have posted the example in Codepen. I think with some tweaks you could get it looking more like the example.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bcFIo)

```
h2 {
    font-size: 130px; 
    font-family: Arial;
    color: hsl(330, 100%, 50%); 
    text-shadow: 2px 0px hsl(330, 100%, 25%),
          3px 2px 0px hsla(330, 100%, 15%, 0.5),              
          3px  3px hsl(350, 100%, 50%), 
          5px  3px hsl(350, 100%, 25%), 
          6px 2px 3px hsla(350, 100%, 15%, 0.5),              
          6px  9px hsl(20, 100%, 50%), 
          8px  9px hsl(20, 100%, 25%), 
          9px 2px 9px hsla(20, 100%, 15%, 0.5),              
          9px  18px hsl(50, 100%, 50%),
          11px  18px hsl(50, 100%, 25%), 
          12px 2px 18px hsla(50, 100%, 15%, 0.5),              
          12px  30px hsl(70, 100%, 50%), 
          14px  30px hsl(70, 100%, 25%), 
          15px 2px 30px hsla(70, 100%, 15%, 0.5),              
          15px  45px hsl(90, 100%, 50%), 
          17px  45px hsl(90, 100%, 25%), 
          17px 2px 45px hsla(90, 100%, 15%, 0.5);
}
```